# The tap on the addChild viewController does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am making a drawer menu.

The tableView is on top of the `DrawerMenuViewController` that was `addChild` to the `ParentViewController`.

When you open the drawer and tap the tableView cell on `DrawerMenuViewController`, there is no response.

- `didSelectRowAt` is not called.
- `delegate` is set.
- I put a button instead of `tableView`, but I couldn't press that button (the method called in `touchUpInside` wasn't called)

Why can't I tap the `tableView Cell`?

`DrawerMenuViewController` is just to the left of `ParentViewController`.
Because `DrawerMenuViewController` wants to come out from the right according to swipe

```
- TabBarController
  - NavigationController
    - ParentViewController
      - DrawerMenuViewController
```

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {   
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menuViewController = DrawerMenuViewController()
        menuViewController.view.frame = CGRect(
            x: view.frame.maxX,
            y: 0,
            width: view.bounds.width,
            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        view.addSubview(menuViewController.view)
        addChild(menuViewController)
        menuViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

Supplement

DrawerMenuViewController is just to the left of ParentViewController.
Because DrawerMenuViewController wants to come out from the right according to swipe

[image]

Comment: Change `tabBarController?.view.addSubview(menuViewController.view)` to `self.view.addSubview(menuViewController.view) ` ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan
Thank you for answering! Sorry, this is my description mistake and `view.addSubview(menuViewController.view)` is the actual description.
Even so, there is no tap response as well

Comment: You wrote: `x: view.frame.maxX` -- do you see the menu where you expect it to be? What do you see in the [view debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html)?

Comment: @Yonat 
Yes.　I expect it.
I added explanation. please check

Answer (score 1):

1. One reason why didSelectRowAt function not getting called is, even though you say you've set who the delegate is that the tableView was not setup correctly.

Just to make sure that you've set the delegate and datasource in in the right place:

extension ParentViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

}
and in ParentViewController's viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

XCode will ask if you want to insert required function stubs.

2. When you do

   `menuViewController.view.frame = CGRect(
           x: view.frame.maxX,
           y: 0,
           width: view.bounds.width,
           height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)`

it looks like your origin is out of bounds because of the x coordinates

Comment: Thank you for answering.

`tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`
Are these two correct for the ParentViewController even though the MenuViewController has it?
and I update question. please check

Comment: It should be in the viewcontroller file that has the tableView